# IIS 7.5: How do I compare the configuration of two "applications"?

Tags: iis, windows-7, configuration, iis-7.5

On my Windows 7 dev machine, I have two applications configured on IIS 7.5: Both have the same web.config, but one of them works and the other doesn't (no HTTP reply, browser keeps waiting forever).

I'm wondering if the IIS settings for these directories are different. Is there an option in IIS manager (or maybe using some command-line tool) to output the configuration for a specific directory (like script handlers, authentication, etc.) into a text file?

Comment: Give a look at a similar answer for iis 7:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788266/how-to-compare-if-the-configuration-is-different-for-iis